# AngularJS and Q.fcall

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

Angulars `$q` is a promise/deferred implementation inspired by Kris Kowal's Q.

In Q, you create a promise with

```
var myPromise = Q.fcall(myFunction);
```

Here the `myFunction` will be invoked asynchronously, a promise is placed in the `myPromise` variable and the code execution continues.

The [only example](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) Angular gives for creating a promise is using javascript `timeout` function, which to me seems like a verbose hack compared to the above Q example. So in Angular I would write

```
function asyncWorker(name) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  setTimeout(function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
      deferred.resolve(myFunction);
    });
  }, 1000);

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

The above would be identical to the one-liner at the top.

I hoped that `$q.fcall` would have worked but I get:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$q.fcall(function() { return 'a'; })')
```

So what's the most straightforward way of asynchronously invoking a function and returning a promise in AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, cleaner alternative is injecting Angular's `$timeout` and let's say again that function `myFunction` is the work I want to do asynchroniously, I'll just do:

```
function doWorkAsync() {
   return $timeout(myFunction, 10);
}
```

and `doWorkAsync` will return a promise that will be resolved when `myFunction` has finished it's work.

For unit testing I can call `$timeout.flush()` to fire the timeout function instantly.

Comment: It's a good answer, but worth clarifgin that it doesn't perfectly emulate `fcall` like using `defer()` does, because `defer` can be run synchronously like `fcall` but `$timeout` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this

```
function doWorkAsync() {
   var defer = $q.defer();
   //do some work async and on a callback 
   asyncWork(function(data)) {
      defer.resolve(data);
   }
   return defer.promise;
}
```

Now you call this function

```
doWorkAsync().then(function(data));
```

Number of angularJS library function already return a promise on invocation. Like `$timeout`,`$http`, `$resource`.

Comment: no, what I'm asking is how to create that `asyncWork` if it's some real work you have to do and not an async service you call like `$http`.

Comment: As i understand javascript is single threaded (over simplification). You need to look at WebWorker https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: @vertti: What do you  mean by "real work"? Why would you need promises if it does not have an async component?

Comment: I just want to write async component myself. So basically I want to do exactly what the typical promise example does, return a promise and then execute asynchronous code. What I'm asking is that using that   `timeout` structure for every async code block seems really verbose compared to `Q.fcall(doAsyncWork)`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is very smart, but it works for me:

```
function fcall(someValues) {
    var deferrd = $q.defer();
    deferrd.resolve(someValues);
    return deferrd.promise;
}

fcall(123).then(function(values) {
    console.log(values); // 123
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function createPromise(func) {
        return function (params) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $timeout(function () {
                try {
                    var rtn = func(params);
                    deferred.resolve(rtn);
                }
                catch (ex) {
                    deferred.reject();
                }

            })
            return deferred.promise
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $q as a constructor similar to how ES6 works.

```
function asyncGreet(name) {
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');
  });
}
```

[angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#-q-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

You can mimick `Q.fcall(fn)` using `$q.when().then(fn)`. It is slightly more verbose but it works the same.

```
var myPromise = $q.when().then(myFunction);
```

where `myFunction` can be either asynchronous or synchronous, and will be called with undefined arguments.

**Working example:**

```
// Node.js
var Q = require('q');
var updatePromise = Q.fcall(function() {
    if (isUpdate) {
        return doAsyncUpdate();
    } else {
        return doSyncDelete();
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    handleError(err);
});

// AngularJS
['$q', function($q) {
    var updatePromise = $q.when().then(function() {
        if (isUpdate) {
            return doAsyncUpdate();
        } else {
            return doSyncDelete();
        }
    }).catch(function(err) {
        handleError(err);
    });
}]
```

Documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when.

Note that `$q.when` works the same as `Q.when`.